# Some questions about the Exercise $3.15$ in Jech Set Theory and the Axiom of Choice.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have $3$ questions about the following exercise in Jech Set Theory (Exercise $3.15$ ($ii$)):

> Show that the set of all finite one-to-one sequences in a Dedekind-finite set is Dedekind-finite.

Part of my solution:

Assume that it is Dedekind-infinite. Then, it has a countable subset. Call it $S = \{S_i \mid i<\omega\}$, where $S_i$'s are finite one-to-one sequences. Now, let $s = \bigcup_{i<\omega} \operatorname{ran}(S_{i})$. It is easy to show that $s$ is not finite, so it is infinite. My first question is: Can I now say directly that $s$ is countably infinite without the Axiom of Choice? If this is valid, then we would arrive at a contradiction since it is a subset of the original set.

In case this cannot be said without the Axiom of Choice, I have thought about the following:

For $a \in s$, let $n(a)$ be the least finite ordinal $i$ such that $a \in \operatorname{ran}(S_{i})$. Now, define the ordering $\prec$ on $s$ by:

$$(a \prec b) \ \ \ \text{iff} \ \ \ ((n(a) < n(b)) \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ (n(a) = n(b) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \text{$a$'s index is less than $b$'s index in the common range}))$$

Now, since this is a well-order on $s$, and $s$ is infinite, we can form a countable subset of $s$ by:

$$a_0 = \text{the least element of $s$}$$
$$a_{n+1} = \text{the least element of $s \setminus \{a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$}$$

My second question is: Is this approach correct?

Finally, my last question is a follow up to this exercise: What if the question asked the same thing but with Dedekind-finite sequences? Can we prove it in that case without the Axiom of Choice? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't say that a countable union of finite sets is countable without appealing to the axiom of choice. The second approach is indeed correct.

For the Dedekind-finite sequences, that's a very nice question, and that is more intricate. Of course you mean *injective* sequences, otherwise just the finite sequences are already Dedekind-infinite (fix $a$ and consider $s_n$ to be the sequence which is just $n$ times $a$).

But now comes the question, what exactly do we mean by that.

1. Do we mean just injective functions from a subset of $X$ to $X$? In that case, there's no reason to expect that the result is Dedekind-finite. For example, if $X$ can be mapped onto $\omega$, i.e. it has a Dedekind-infinite power set, then we can simply pick countable many subsets and consider the identity function. But note that it is certainly possible that those countably many subsets are indeed *finite*, which is now in contradiction with what you just proved.
2. Do we mean injective functions from cardinals of subsets of $X$ to $X$? That's not always a possible definition. If $X$ is amorphous, then every subset is finite or co-finite, but we cannot choose a representative for each infinite cardinal, since that would allow us to define a surjection from $X$ onto $\omega$ (take the complements, these are finite, now map each element in $X$ to the least index of a finite set in which it appears, or $0$ otherwise; easily this map has an infinite range).

So we are in a situation where "the right definition" is not obvious at all. So there's no good answer, other than "it's complicated and it depends on both $X$ and on what exactly you mean by that".

Comment: Oh, now I see why I cannot imagine a Dedekind-finite sequence, thank you.